# Aptana 3 PHP var colours not updating with theme

Tags: colors, aptana

How can I get my php vars to match whatever theme I am running. They seem to stay black even if I switch to say.. Choco or nightlion themes. It's really annoying and I just can't see anywhere in the theme menus how to change php var colours.

Any help much appreciated :)

Comment: Code sample for what you want to change will help a bit.

Comment: Any .php file that has a variable has black foreground colour for the text regardless of the theme. The background colour changes as theme dictates though. Seems like something is overriding php colours but I don't know where the colour of php vars are set in aptana.

Comment: What do you get when you place the caret on the variable and do Ctrl+Shift+P (show scope)? Also, checkout https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Themes

Comment: I found the setting! Prefs > PHP > Editor > Syntax Coloring.
From here I was able to alter the variables etc colours for PHP docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the setting! (On a mac, it appears this might be different on other os's)

```
Prefs > PHP > Editor > Syntax Coloring.
```

From here I was able to alter the variables etc colours for PHP docs

Comment: Hmmm, are you using Aptana for your PHP editing, or are you using PDT on top of Aptana?

Comment: I'm using default PHP settings in Aptana 3 standalone. Which I believe is not PDT.

Comment: I asked that because Aptana Studio's PHP preference path is not the one  you mentioned above. It's: `Prefs > Aptana Studio > Editors > PHP`.

Comment: On a mac it's as I wrote above. On my ubuntu box it's not though. I am still looking for it's location on that one. Will update when I get a chance to track it down.